# Coating for concrete staircase

Tags: concrete, paint, exterior

I would like to apply some kind of coating to this concrete staircase that would involve color other than the native.

[image]

I am not sure if just regular exterior primer and paint would be durable because of direct vertical exposure to weather. What are my options? I would also like something less complicated than epoxy. Is there a colored sealant that would be more resistant to weather than just regular paint or do you think paint is fine?

Comment: The "exterior" graded primer and paint have already taken into account the impacts from the environment and weather. Just find the one that is suitable for cement-based material. Don't use water-based paint though.

Comment: The exterior primer I use (Zinsser) is water-based. Should I use oil based?

Comment: I would shy away from painting concrete with water-based primer/paint, it usually is not durable. For applying oil-based primer, make sure the surface has completely dried.

Comment: can you recommend any product in specific?

Comment: I suggest talking to your paint supplier who is knowledgeable, not the store clerk though. Don't forget to mention it is for outdoor stair use, which might need a special product for wearing and abrasion.

Comment: **PAINT IS SLIPPERY, ESPECIALLY WHEN WET!** A nice smooth coat is perfect for those block walls, but will result in a trip to the hospital when descending the stairs in the rain. Make sure you get a paint that has some grit in it, or get an appropriate grit additive to ensure that you have traction when walking up and down. Your local paint store (not big-box, as noted) may cost you a few bucks more, but could save your life with their knowledge and proper product line.

Comment: You narrowly skirted product recommendation prohibition in your post, but you bludgeoned right into that off-topic realm with your comments. I'm not sure why you didn't just read some labels. They tend to make it quite clear right on the front what they're for. This is not an odd use case.

Answer (score 4):

Concrete floor paint, as used in showrooms and garages will do just fine. Different colours are available, and some mix with epoxy, giving an even harder finish.

Might be an idea to mark the edges of the treads in a lighter colour, for safety reasons.

Comment: Anti-slip additives (grit) are also a good idea for stairs.

Comment: yes, sprinkle some dry silica sand on the wet paint to provide grip and increase the durability of the paint.

Comment: Any of the surface treatments that are applicable to concrete paths can be used here,